# Static typing an abstractmethod of an Enum

Tags: python, enums, abstract, mypy

From abstract super-class enumerations `Action` and `Activity` there are the inherited enumerations:

- `ActivityA` upon which `ActionA` can be performed; and
- `ActivityB` upon which `ActionB` can be performed.

How can a type declaration be added to the `action` argument of the `perform` method on the abstract `Activity` method such that MyPy will respect the inheritance or which action applies to which activity?

```py
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from enum import EnumMeta, IntEnum


class ABCEnumMeta(EnumMeta, ABCMeta):
    ...
    

class Action(ABC, IntEnum, metaclass=ABCEnumMeta):
    ...


class ActionA(Action):
    start = 1
    stop = 2

class ActionB(Action):
    start = 1
    pause = 2
    resume = 3
    complete = 4
    fail = 5

class Activity(ABC, IntEnum, metaclass=ABCEnumMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def perform(
        self: "Activity",
        action,                                      # <- This line
    ) -> str:
        ...

class ActivityA(Activity):
    this = 1
    that = 2
    
    def perform(
        self: "ActivityA",
        action: ActionA,
    ) -> str:
      return f"A: {action.name} {self.name}"

        
class ActivityB(Activity):
    something = 1
    another = 2
    
    def perform(
        self: "ActivityB",
        action: ActionB,
    ) -> str:
      return f"B: {action.name} {self.name}"


print( ActivityB.something.perform(ActionB.pause) )
print( ActivityA.this.perform(ActionA.stop) )
print( ActivityB.another.perform(ActionA.start) )
print( ActivityA.that.perform(ActionB.fail) )
```

The `mypy.ini` settings file being used is:

```
[mypy]
disallow_any_expr        = True
disallow_any_decorated   = True
disallow_any_explicit    = True
disallow_any_generics    = True
disallow_subclassing_any = True
disallow_untyped_calls   = True
disallow_untyped_defs    = True
disallow_incomplete_defs = True
```

The output from MyPy is:

> ```
> test_enum.py:26: error: Function is missing a type annotation for one or more arguments
> test_enum.py:26: error: Type of decorated function contains type "Any" ("Callable[[Activity, Any], str]")
> test_enum.py:56: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityB" has incompatible type "ActionA"; expected "ActionB"
> test_enum.py:57: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityA" has incompatible type "ActionB"; expected "ActionA"
> ```

*(The last two errors are expected.)*

In this situation, I would normally use generics and define:

```py
A = TypeVar("A", bound=Action)


class Activity(ABC, Generic[A], IntEnum, metaclass=ABCEnumMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def perform(
        self: "Activity",
        action A,
    ) -> str:
        ...


class ActivityA(Activity[ActionA]):
    ...


class ActivityB(Activity[ActionB]):
    ...
```

However, the `Enum` class raises exceptions when you try to add in a generic.

How could this be solved to properly define the argument types of the abstract method?

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution (since an `Enum` cannot have a `Generic` mixin) is to use the super-type `Action` in the abstract parent method (rather than trying to use the sub-types via generics):

```py
class Activity(ABC, IntEnum, metaclass=ABCEnumMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def perform(
        self: "Activity",
        action: Action,
    ) -> str:
        ...
```

This will then give the errors:

> ```
> test_enum.py:36: error: Argument 1 of "perform" is incompatible with supertype "Activity"; supertype defines the argument type as "Action"
> test_enum.py:36: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
> test_enum.py:36: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
> test_enum.py:47: error: Argument 1 of "perform" is incompatible with supertype "Activity"; supertype defines the argument type as "Action"
> test_enum.py:47: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
> test_enum.py:47: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
> test_enum.py:56: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityB" has incompatible type "ActionA"; expected "ActionB"
> test_enum.py:57: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityA" has incompatible type "ActionB"; expected "ActionA"
> ```

The additional errors can be explicitly [locally silenced](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker) using `# type: ignore[override]`:

```py
class ActivityA(Activity):
    this = 1
    that = 2
    
    def perform(  # type: ignore[override]
        self: "ActivityA",
        action: ActionA,
    ) -> str:
      return f"A: {action.name} {self.name}"

        
class ActivityB(Activity):
    something = 1
    another = 2
    
    def perform(  # type: ignore[override]
        self: "ActivityB",
        action: ActionB,
    ) -> str:
      return f"B: {action.name} {self.name}"
```

Once those errors are locally silenced then the output is just the two expected errors:

> ```
> test_enum.py:56: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityB" has incompatible type "ActionA"; expected "ActionB"
> test_enum.py:57: error: Argument 1 to "perform" of "ActivityA" has incompatible type "ActionB"; expected "ActionA"
> ```

While this makes it explicitly clear that the abstract parent method should take an `Action` type in the parameter, it does not indicate from the abstract parent class that the children should be expecting a specific sub-type (as generics would allow). Therefore, this is only a partial solution; a better solution would be to "fix" the `Enum` class (or to sub-class `Enum`) to allow a `Generic` mixin.